# Refilling Epson printer cartridge with genuine Epson inks

Tags: printer, inkjet-printer, ink

Epson's latest printer inkjet series finally replaced cartridges with external ink tanks that users can refill with their ink. This is great, as it pushes ink prices as low as possible while minimizing waste.

But since old(er) printers don't have the same technology and some users bought aftermarket cheaper inks or even refill cartridges I was wondering whether it would be now feasible to buy refillable cartridges and then simply buy Epson's genuine ink and refill with them with it? This would mean that your printer would be using genuine Epson ink, but your running costs would be much lower and you'd save the planes some plastic waste.

Why would I want to do this? Well because aftermarket ink can damage print head in ways that one can't imagine. Mine apparently somehow eroded printer head so individual inks started to mix inside of the head. Nozzles are fine, but cyan mixes with magenta inside of head. A friend of mine that works at an official Epson service told me that this is likely due to aftermarket ink and nothing else. He told me that people neglect this fact because these changes and damage is gradual and not immediate. It's like smoking. You feel quite ok until you become seriously ill.

### The main questions are of course:

1. Are primary colours (CMYK) always of the same *color* (hue, intensity, darkness...) regardless of printer type? So Magenta is always *the same* magenta whichever Epson printer you'd use (or with other manufacturers)
2. How about with photo printers? Are these colours also always the same?
3. Has anybody tried it?

> ***Note:*** I own an Epson Stylus Photo RX640 which uses a specifically expensive set of inks. I would surely take advantage of the availability of genuine Epson inks.

Comment: 1) No; Every manufacture uses different inks.  2) No; Every manufacture is different 3) I wasn't even aware Epson offered Epson ink.  If Epson offers refillable cartridges, and you fill it with Epson Ink, there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Ink formulations can vary greatly, even within a given manufacturer's print line. So no, you can't depend on Epson inks for one printer to be good inks to use on another printer. The chemical formulation, while LESS likely to be damaging, could still do funny things to the 'wrong' printer, depending on a lot of variables that you don't have any way to know about or measure. That said, I'd expect far less problems with Epson Ink than with third-party ink - Epson's inks are likely to be related, and thus less likely to break things.

Comment: Colors vary between/within manufacturers, and different printers have different droplet sizes, which affects requirements. I've seen color shifts using high quality 3rd party ink. It's especially pronounced mixing OEM & 3rd party catridges. This is especially acute on a photo printer, or using photo inks on a 3-color printer or vice versa for the matching colors. There are 3rd party professional inks for photo printers that are at least as good as the OEM inks, but the collection of colors is a system. All of the colors need to be from the same source collection, you can't mix & match brands.